# What is causing URLs to be blocked in Web Master Tools on BigCommerce store?

Tags: bigcommerce, google-search-console

My client has a store in BigCommerce and is using Google Web Master Tools to monitor search performance. Google is telling the client that certain URLs are blocked on mobile by the robots.txt file. It seems any URL that ends with `?sort=newest` is being blocked.

The contents of the HTTP robots.txt file is:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /account.php
Disallow: /cart.php
Disallow: /checkout.php
Disallow: /finishorder.php
Disallow: /login.php
Disallow: /orderstatus.php
Disallow: /postreview.php
Disallow: /productimage.php
Disallow: /productupdates.php
Disallow: /remote.php
Disallow: /search.php
Disallow: /viewfile.php
Disallow: /wishlist.php
Disallow: /admin/
Disallow: /_socialshop/
```

The contents on the HTTPS robots.txt file is:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /

User-agent: google-xrawler
Allow: /feeds/*
```

Obviosuly, no mention of `?sort=newest` in the robots files.

How can I stop the `?sort=newest` pages from being blocked on mobile search?

Comment: While I understand your question, blocking url filters is actually best practice. You can read more about it under https://moz.com/ugc/guide-to-ecommerce-facets-filters-and-categories under the heading "No Indexed Filters"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I understand your question, blocking url filters is actually best practice. You can read more about it under on [Moz](http://moz.com/ugc/guide-to-ecommerce-facets-filters-and-categories) under the heading "No Indexed Filters".

[Some additional information](https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/URL-Parameters-and-Duplicate-Content) is offered by BC around this and how to indicate to google what Search Parameter should be crawled, if any.